# Mac (Designed for iPad) not using latest build?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm working on an app with Supported Destinations

- iPhone
- iPad
- Mac (Designed for iPad)

When I build and run for iPhone or iPad, it works as expected. However whenever I make some code changes and build and run for Mac (Designed for iPad) it does not include the latest changes.

Workaround: if I use **Clean Build Folder...** the next Mac (Designed for iPad) build shows the latest changes, but I don't want to have to do this for every build. Any suggestions?

Comment: File a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Did that, but Feedback doesn't provide very prompt feedback.